# bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?) when importing Connection from @solana/web3.js

Tags: web3.js

When attempting to import Connection from @solana/web3.js, this appears when it is run:

```
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
```

It appears to still run, but I am concerned about what it may impact. Has anyone come across a solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution ?

Comment: Not yet. I am still experiencing this issue. I'm not worried about it until I get to production with my project. Maybe soon the library will be updated to fix it for everyone.

Comment: I've tried all the above solution but it didn't worked for me. Will update when I'll succeed in solving this.

Comment: Tried the below answers, still can not get it work in Mac. ( I have latest python, xcode dev tools, node-gyp)

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers above go to the root cause of the issue and won't solve it, depending on how you are building the environment and running the application.

In my case, the error was occurring in an acceptance tests setup using a very simple docker image starting from `node:21.4.0-bookworm-slim`. Notice the `*-slim` part, which means an image with the absolute minimal preinstalled packages.

```
FROM node:21.4.0-bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /code
COPY package* tsconfig.json /code
RUN npm install
```

Of course, running the tests, which happens to use `bigint-buffer`, was displaying the warning. Although nothing was failing, it was a performance concern (maybe...). In any case, I can't sleep with these warnings polluting my terminal.

```
$ docker compose exec client npm run test:acceptance

> solana-client@1.0.0 test:acceptance
> rm -rf ./dist/* && tsc && node --test dist/*.test.js

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
✔ reads own balance (53.348432ms)
▶ creates/deletes PDA
  ✔ fails for non-admin user (12.346694ms)
  ✔ fails for insuficient lamports (7.776273ms)
  ...
```

Running `npm run rebuild` as suggested inside the container didn't help. Digging deeper, it turns out that `bigint-buffer` uses native C bindings for performance reasons, but as such it requires certain dependencies to exist on the host to compile the file written in C. In case these dependencies are not there, it will fallback gracefully to JS implementation, which will still work, but will be less performant.

The build is performed by a tool called `node-gyp`. This is not very clear from the `bigint-buffer` perspective, but in `node-gyp` the dependencies are clearly described in their [README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#on-unix):

- A supported version of `Python`
- `make`
- A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like `GCC`

In my Debian setup, all I needed was to install `python3` and `build-essential` (which contains `make` and `gcc`), adding the following to the `Dockerfile` *before* running `npm install` (so the OS dependencies are there when `bigint-buffer` is installed by `npm`):

```
RUN apt update \
    && apt install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        python3
```

If you are running this locally, of course you can just install the equivalent dependencies directly on your computer. Of course if you are using another distro, MacOS or Windows you'll need different dependencies, but the spirit is same.

And done! Optimized native big numbers are now used and no warning is displayed anymore!

Comment: Thanks for this investigation. It works nicely.

Comment: Installing build-essential worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and `npm rebuild` solved the issue.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Even replacing node_modules entirely did not fix this for me.

Comment: `  After some tinkering around with the project I ended up using this command and it worked as well. I believe it has something to do with the react version being used on your local environment. Would you mind trying these commands? `npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install`

Comment: Interesting. I'm into Svelte and never installed React. The system is fresh and I don't think I installed Svelte yet either. After I ran `ncu -u` and did install again, I continue to experience the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install bigint-buffer
```

This utility is necessary because BigInts, as proposed, do not support direct conversion between Buffers (or UInt8Arrays), but rather require conversion from buffers to hexadecimal strings then to BigInts, which is suboptimal.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-buffer

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `npm rebuild`? That seemed to fix it for me and a few other people on discord...

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Even replacing node_modules entirely did not fix this for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm install bigint-buffer
2. npm rebuild
3. npm start

--> It work for me

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of the @609Consulting answer.