# bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?) ,npm rebuild doesn't get rid of the error

Tags: buffer

I'm trying to make my javascript code that uses @solana/web3.js run faster. I tried npm rebuild and also npm install bigint-buffer, and neither got rid of the warning. Does the display of this warning indicate that the script is slower because of it needing to use some other method of converting things? I have this warning in both my local computer and in an AWS lambda function, so I don't think the problem is some sort of system configuration. Any other ideas for getting rid of this warning?

Comment: Does https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4918/289 help?

Comment: @CallumM I've tried that, and it doesn't seem to help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?) when importing Connection from @solana/web3.js](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4077/bigint-failed-to-load-bindings-pure-js-will-be-used-try-npm-run-rebuild-whe)